# How to disable "set -x"?

Tags: shell, debugging

For some debugging purposes I enabled the command `set -x`. Now the output of my Bash shell looks like this:

```
$ ls
+ ls --color=auto
Certificates  Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Dropbox ...
```

How can I disable `set -x` so I won't see stuff like `+ ls --color=auto`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You just need to run `set +x`

From `man bash`:

```
Using + rather than - causes these options to be turned  off.
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use `set -x` within a subshell, so that this option is automatically reset:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch one
(
    set -x
    touch two
)
touch three

# Only "+ touch two" will get printed
```